# How to get a unique name for each uploaded file using uploadify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I am uploading files using jQuery uploadify plugin. All files are uploaded into same directory. When I try to upload a file twice, it give me following error.

```
filename.gif (4.3KB) - IO Error
```

I want to upload a file with unique name every time. There are many other users uploading files in same directory. So there is a chance that two users share same file name. How can I avoid overwritten.

**My Code:**

```
$('.SingleFileUpload').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : '/uploads',
        'auto'      : true,
        'queueID'   : 'fileQueue',
        'removeCompleted':false,
        'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                            $(event.target).closest('form').append( '<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_file" value="' + response + '">' );
                        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using javascript is good or safe for this, one method I use is to name each file by calculate its [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) on server side.

Comment: Ok. `php` tag is added. So we can solve it in **uploadify.php**

Answer (score 3):

To start off, reject duplicate file names:

```
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        if (file_exists($targetFile)){
            echo 'File does already exist, choose another name!';
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            echo '1';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

You can prefix all of your file names by the ID of the user + an underscore (or any character to separate the ID from the file name, to avoid `UID1 + 2file == UID12 + file`.

Instead of forcing the user to choose another name, you can also implement an automated name change: Either by adding a prefix and/or postfix, or by calculating the hash of the file. The last option also prevents duplicate files (same name, same contents) from appearing at the server.

Comment: I'd also add a timestamp, while you're at it.

Comment: I've proposed two options: Either let the user freely choose the file name (for "pretty" / "readable" file names, so that the user can easily refer back to it), or a forced unique name (suggested by the server).

Comment: Thanks for reply. So this code is for **uploadify.php**. Is it necessary to initialize `$targetFolder` in **uploadify.php** ? We have an option `folder` to set it in jQuery.

Comment: @Student Do not trust anything from client side, all could be faked.

Comment: @Student Open your version of `uploadify.php`, and edit `move_uploaded_file(...)` in accordance with the format in my answer. The important part is `if(file_exists($targetFile)){...}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm duplicating the filename and adding the copynr at the end. like:
filename(2)
filename(3)
filename(4) etc.

```
$('#upload').uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'resources/plugins/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'resources/plugins/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'      : 'resources/plugins/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'         : 'uploads/',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : false,
        'fileDesc'       : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;',
        'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;',
        onComplete: function (evt, queueID, fileObj, response, data){
            alert(response); // = uploaded filename
        }
```

just the uploadify JS part (not using the check method!)
Now the uploadify.php part

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = '.'.pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = substr($_FILES['Filedata']['name'],0,-strlen($ext));
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $filename . $ext;

    while(file_exists($targetFile)){
        preg_match('/\([0-9]{1,}\)$/', $filename,$matches);
        if(!empty($matches)){
            preg_match('/[0-9]{1,}/', $matches[0],$nr);
            $filename = substr($filename,0,-strlen($matches[0])) . '('.(((int)$nr[0])+1).')';
        }else
            $filename .= '(2)';
        $targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) .$filename . $ext;
    }

if(!is_dir($targetPath)) mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
echo $filename.$ext;}
```

HTH

Comment: I am working on a similar setup but have a problem with large files. If `move_uploaded_file` takes to long, no filename is returned from uploadify.php. I even tried setting `successTimeout` to something like 3 minutes but that didn't help either.

Comment: are you using the correct php.ini settings for large files? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339519/sending-formdata-with-uploadify-not-working-with-large-file-size