# Sending formData with Uploadify not working with Large file size

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I am using this uploadify plugin . I am  posting variables however everything works fine but when i upload a file size greater than 5mb it doesnt post data .Here is my code and debug information . I have tried changing size limits even set to  0 which means no limit .changed the upload limit settings in php.ini but still it wont work

```
                //Upload Song#2




$('#upload_song2').uploadify({
     'auto'          : true,
     'multi'         : false,   
     'fileTypeDesc'  : 'Mp3 Files',
     'fileTypeExts'  : '*.mp3',
     'swf'           : 'uploadify.swf',
     'uploader'      : 'artist_music_process.php' ,
      'sizeLimit': 25600, // 25 MB


  'onUploadStart' : function(file) 
 {
     console.log(file);
     $('#upload_song2').uploadify("settings",
      "formData", {
      "column":'album_song_name2',
      'artist_id' : '<?php echo $artist_details['id']; ?>',
      'username' : '<?php echo $artist_details['username'];?>'


      });
  },










      'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) 


      {
          alert(data);
        $("#container").notify("create", {
        title: 'Success',
        text: file.name+' Uploaded with success'
         });      

        $('#txt_song2').val(file.name);
        $('#hid_song2').val(data);





      }
      // Your options here

    }); //uploadify ends
```

This is my Debug Code .

```
                                                ---SWFUpload Instance Info---
                Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
                Movie Name: SWFUpload_0
                Settings:
                    upload_url:               /desi/artist_music_process.php
                    flash_url:                uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1347196919191
                    use_query_string:         false
                    requeue_on_error:         false
                    http_success:             
                    assume_success_timeout:   30
                    file_post_name:           Filedata
                    post_params:              [object Object]
                    file_types:               *.mp3
                    file_types_description:   Mp3 Files
                    file_size_limit:          0
                    file_upload_limit:        0
                    file_queue_limit:         999
                    debug:                    true
                    prevent_swf_caching:      true
                    button_placeholder_id:    upload_song2
                    button_placeholder:       Not Set
                    button_image_url:         /desi/
                    button_width:             120
                    button_height:            30
                    button_text:              
                    button_text_style:        color: #000000; font-size: 16pt;
                    button_text_top_padding:  0
                    button_text_left_padding: 0
                    button_action:            -100
                    button_disabled:          false
                    custom_settings:          [object Object]
                Event Handlers:
                    swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
                    file_dialog_start_handler assigned: true
                    file_queued_handler assigned:       true
                    file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
                    upload_start_handler assigned:      true
                    upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
                    upload_error_handler assigned:      true
                    upload_success_handler assigned:    true
                    upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
                    debug_handler assigned:             true

                ---SWFUpload Instance Info---
                Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
                Movie Name: SWFUpload_1
                Settings:
                    upload_url:               /desi/artist_music_process.php
                    flash_url:                uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1347196919200
                    use_query_string:         false
                    requeue_on_error:         false
                    http_success:             
                    assume_success_timeout:   30
                    file_post_name:           Filedata
                    post_params:              [object Object]
                    file_types:               *.mp3
                    file_types_description:   Mp3 Files
                    file_size_limit:          0
                    file_upload_limit:        0
                    file_queue_limit:         999
                    debug:                    true
                    prevent_swf_caching:      true
                    button_placeholder_id:    upload_song
                    button_placeholder:       Not Set
                    button_image_url:         /desi/
                    button_width:             120
                    button_height:            30
                    button_text:              
                    button_text_style:        color: #000000; font-size: 16pt;
                    button_text_top_padding:  0
                    button_text_left_padding: 0
                    button_action:            -100
                    button_disabled:          false
                    custom_settings:          [object Object]
                Event Handlers:
                    swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
                    file_dialog_start_handler assigned: true
                    file_queued_handler assigned:       true
                    file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
                    upload_start_handler assigned:      true
                    upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
                    upload_error_handler assigned:      true
                    upload_success_handler assigned:    true
                    upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
                    debug_handler assigned:             true

                ---SWFUpload Instance Info---
                Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
                Movie Name: SWFUpload_2
                Settings:
                    upload_url:               /desi/artist_music_process.php
                    flash_url:                uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1347196919207
                    use_query_string:         false
                    requeue_on_error:         false
                    http_success:             
                    assume_success_timeout:   30
                    file_post_name:           Filedata
                    post_params:              [object Object]
                    file_types:               *.jpg; *.png
                    file_types_description:   Image Files
                    file_size_limit:          0
                    file_upload_limit:        0
                    file_queue_limit:         999
                    debug:                    true
                    prevent_swf_caching:      true
                    button_placeholder_id:    upload_album_img
                    button_placeholder:       Not Set
                    button_image_url:         /desi/
                    button_width:             120
                    button_height:            30
                    button_text:              
                    button_text_style:        color: #000000; font-size: 16pt;
                    button_text_top_padding:  0
                    button_text_left_padding: 0
                    button_action:            -100
                    button_disabled:          false
                    custom_settings:          [object Object]
                Event Handlers:
                    swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
                    file_dialog_start_handler assigned: true
                    file_queued_handler assigned:       true
                    file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
                    upload_start_handler assigned:      true
                    upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
                    upload_error_handler assigned:      true
                    upload_success_handler assigned:    true
                    upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
                    debug_handler assigned:             true

                SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
                SWF DEBUG: 
                SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
                SWF DEBUG: Build Number:           SWFUPLOAD 2.2.0
                SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
                SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             /desi/artist_music_process.php
                SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.mp3
                SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:      mp3
                SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
                SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: Mp3 Files (*.mp3)
                SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        0 bytes
                SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      0
                SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       999
                SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
                SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
                SWF DEBUG: 
                SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Single Select. Allowed file types: *.mp3
                SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
                SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
                SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
                SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
                SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: username=basit
                SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: column=album_song_name2
                SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: artist_id=7
                SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for upload.  Starting upload to /desi/artist_music_process.php for File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 4128768. Total: 10070528
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 10070528. Total: 10070528
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadSuccess: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0 Response Received: true Data: Array
                SWF DEBUG: (
                SWF DEBUG: )
                SWF DEBUG: Array
                SWF DEBUG: (
                SWF DEBUG: )
                SWF DEBUG: 
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
                SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Single Select. Allowed file types: *.mp3
                SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
                SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_1
                SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
                SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_1
                SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: username=basit
                SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: column=album_song_name2
                SWF DEBUG: Global Post Item: artist_id=7
                SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for upload.  Starting upload to /desi/artist_music_process.php for File ID: SWFUpload_0_1
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_1
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_1. Bytes: 5599328. Total: 5599328
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadSuccess: File ID: SWFUpload_0_1 Response Received: true Data: Array
                SWF DEBUG: (
                SWF DEBUG:     [Filename] => Utay - Copy.mp3
                SWF DEBUG:     [username] => basit
                SWF DEBUG:     [column] => album_song_name2
                SWF DEBUG:     [artist_id] => 7
                SWF DEBUG:     [Upload] => Submit Query
                SWF DEBUG: )
                SWF DEBUG: Array
                SWF DEBUG: (
                SWF DEBUG:     [Filedata] => Array
                SWF DEBUG:         (
                SWF DEBUG:             [name] => Utay - Copy.mp3
                SWF DEBUG:             [type] => application/octet-stream
                SWF DEBUG:             [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpAB62.tmp
                SWF DEBUG:             [error] => 0
                SWF DEBUG:             [size] => 5599328
                SWF DEBUG:         )
                SWF DEBUG: 
                SWF DEBUG: )
                SWF DEBUG: basit_utay - copy.mp3
                SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
```

Comment: have you verified in phpinfo(); that you were able to successfully change the post limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to update your php.ini for uploading large files. You need to change following variables

```
file_uploadsile_uploads
    upload_max_filesize
    max_input_time
    memory_limit
    max_execution_time
    post_max_size
```

Comment: i am working on localhost wamp ... so execution time doesnt matter any how let me change them  .. i tried up to 7 mb working fine but after that its not

Comment: change all  variables, then you can upload large files

Comment: icant find these variables in my php.ini only first one is there
 upload_max_filesize

Comment: Use GOOGLE:), YOU WILL FIND ALL VARIABLES

Comment: post_max_size that was the problem its set to 8M
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. My php ini file was in good standing. I realized that my jpeg image extension was uppercase (.JPG) and I was checking file types on my upload php script for only lowercase extensions. I modified it to reflect both uppercase and lowercase and this resolved my issue to upload files larger than 2mb!

Hope this helps someone!

```
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','JPG','GIF','JPEG','PNG'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
```